# 'An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call. (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL))'

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# and am trying to create a web browser for a specific function
I have Form1 (An invisible form) that calls Form2 (The browser) and monitor to make sure Form2 is always running and if it goes idle close and reopen Form2

I think I'm having an issue with threading, which I setup to run the timer (It's the only way I could work out)

I have determined that it only fails to launch Form2 when I try to call the function from inside the thread

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Browselite;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace BrowseLite
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();

        public static Boolean IdleTimeoutEnabled { get; private set; }
        public static int IdleTimeout { get; private set; }
        public static Boolean ClearRunning { get; private set; }
        public Form2 Browser { get; private set; }
        public static Boolean programmaticClose { get; set; }
        public static Boolean Form2Open { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern Boolean GetLastInputInfo(ref tagLASTINPUTINFO plii);
        public struct tagLASTINPUTINFO
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public Int32 dwTime;

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (RegistryKey RootKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Policies\\BrowseLite"))
                {
                    try
                    {

                        Form1.IdleTimeout = Int32.Parse(RootKey.GetValue("IdleTimeout", -1, RegistryValueOptions.None).ToString());
                        if (Form1.IdleTimeout <= 0)
                        {
                            Form1.IdleTimeoutEnabled = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Form1.IdleTimeoutEnabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Form1.IdleTimeout = 0;
                        Form1.IdleTimeoutEnabled = false;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Form1.IdleTimeout = 0;
                Form1.IdleTimeoutEnabled = false;
            }


            Thread Timer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyTimer));

            Browser = new Form2();
            OpenBrowser();

            Timer.Start();
        }

        private void MyTimer()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                FormCollection OpenForms = Application.OpenForms;
                foreach (Form OpenForm in OpenForms)
                {
                    if (OpenForm.Name.Contains("Form2"))
                    {
                        Form1.Form2Open = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!Form1.Form2Open)
                {
                    Browser.ShowDialog();
                    Form1.Form2Open = true;
                }


                tagLASTINPUTINFO LastInput = new tagLASTINPUTINFO();
                Int32 IdleTime;
                LastInput.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(LastInput);
                LastInput.dwTime = 0;

                if (GetLastInputInfo(ref LastInput))
                {
                    IdleTime = System.Environment.TickCount - LastInput.dwTime;
                    int IdleTimeSet = IdleTimeout * 60 * 1000;
                    if (Form1.IdleTimeoutEnabled)
                    {
                        if (IdleTime >= IdleTimeSet)
                        {
                            if (Form1.ClearRunning == false)
                            {
                                CloseBrowser();
                                OpenBrowser();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Form1.ClearRunning = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000 * 30); //Time in seconds (30)
            }
        }


        private void CloseBrowser()
        {
            Form1.programmaticClose = true;
            Browser.Close();
        }

        private void OpenBrowser()
        {
            Form1.programmaticClose = false;
            Form1.Form2Open = true;
            Browser.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, but as I said... I'm not good with this.

Comment: why are you using this strange function called `StartTimer`? you `async await async await Task.Delay(1000) in infinitive loop`. Why don't you use a normal [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: also this looks like an _XY problem_. What are you trying to do _exactly_? Why are you closing and reopening idle form? Why do you use a Browser component instead of normal browser?

Comment: I am not sure why I initially used that method. I just updated it and still the same result.
I'm working on a browser for kiosk machines. If the user walks away it needs to close the browser and re-open just in case they were stupid enough to login to one of the forms/sites

Comment: There is a special [Windows Single-app Kiosk Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app) for this. Why don't you use it?

Comment: There are several limitations to using the kiosk method in this environment that make it useless to us. Trust me when I say that making a c# application was not my first preference, but I'm so close to the finish line I can practically taste it

Comment: anyway, as you say that you are _"fairly new to C#"_, why do you use all this `Thread` stuff? There is simple [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2) WinForms components for this kind of bicycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that stumbles onto this, I found the answer myself

If setting a variable in the thread. Instead of using

> Form1.Running = true;

instead use

> BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Form1.Running = true), null);

And if calling a function from within the thread use

> BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(**FUNCTION**));

This seems to have completely fixed my issue